# topic_tools transform from launch file?

Tags: ros, topic-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is [topic_tools transform](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform#preview) incapable of being run from a launch file?  Maybe it has a non-standard parser for getting the python imports, and can't handle __ arguments properly?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <node name="radius" pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic"
      args="pub /radius std_msgs/Float32 'data: 1.0' -r 1" />

  <node name="radius_to_diameter" pkg="topic_tools" type="transform"
      args="/radius /diameter std_msgs/Float32 'm.data * 2'" />
</launch>
```

Fails with:

```
process[radius-1]: started with pid [26144]
process[radius_to_diameter-2]: started with pid [26150]
usage: transform [-h] [-i MODULES [MODULES ...]]
                 input output_topic output_type expression
transform: error: unrecognized arguments: __name:=radius_to_diameter __log:=/home/lucasw/.ros/log/.../radius_to_diameter-2.log
[radius_to_diameter-2] process has died [pid 26150, exit code 2, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/topic_tools/transform /radius /diameter std_msgs/Float32 m.data * 2 __name:=radius_to_diameter __log:=/home/lucasw/.ros/log/.../radius_to_diameter-2.log].
```

While

```
rosrun topic_tools transform /radius /diameter std_msgs/Float32 'm.data * 2'
```

works as expected.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214269/topic_tools-transform-from-launch-file?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2015-07-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks it's missing a call to `rospy.myargv` to strip all the extra stuff before trying to parse the args. File an [issue against ros_comm](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/new) (or better yet, a pull request).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-07-22**:
I'll do that.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-07-24**:
https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/645

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-04-14**:
so what is the correct way now?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2021-09-26**:
@Kansai the launch file example in the question now works